# Finding f'(0) in a taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion

While doing questions involving taylor series, I accidentally chanced upon an unorthodox, if more difficult way of solving for $f^{(n)}(0)$ of a given taylor series. I am wondering why it works, if anyone could explain the math.

Say we had this question: the function $f$ is defined by the series $$g(x) = 1-\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{4!}+...+\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{(2n)!}$$

and were asked to find $f''(0)$

1. Textbook method: $$\frac{f''(0)}{2!}= \frac{1}{4!}$$ 
   $$f''(0) = \frac{2}{4!}$$
2. We first find the second derivative of the general term of the series $$\frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n-2}}{(2n)!}$$
   then we substitute in $x=0$ into the summation. Note that all terms of the series equal 0 except for when $n=2$ when we treat $0^0$ as 1; therefore, the series is equal to the general term at $n=2$

$$=\frac{2(-1)^2(2-1)0^0}{4}!=\frac{2}{4!}$$

This second method is arguably more difficult, but does not require you to deal with the coefficients of terms as in the first method. Can anyone explain why they both work?

Comment: Your problem pops up when treating $0^0$ as $1$.

Comment: unfortunately that is the only way the second method works; my calculus textbook does treat $0^0$ as one though

Comment: Your method is perfectly fine: you're just differentiating $g$ twice and plugging $0$ in to the resulting power series for $g''$.

Comment: @Sanath: Among non-negative integers $m$ and $n,$ one can define $n^m$ as the number of functions from an $m$-element set into an $n$-element set. In that context, $0^0=1$ makes sense (the empty function), though not in an analytic context.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: This isn't really a problem. The term in question doesn't really involve $x$, it is constant. In fact, this is exactly how you derive the Taylor coefficients in the first place. You wouldn't hesitate to say that if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f''(0)=2$, would you? No, because you don't write $f''(x)=2x^0$, you write $f''(x)=2$. Same thing here.  It's a symbolic way to represent what happens in the general case, with the implicit understanding that when $n=2$ the $x$ has been differentiated away and there is nothing to plug $0$ into. You really **don't** have $0^0$.